# Firebase Cloud Function Finished with status ''error''

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am writing my first cloud function to send a push notification when a new user signs up with my android app. I have done the basics like installing Node and firebase cli and got my project initialized.

I have written this test function below to log the user id of any user along with their token, who signs up and deployed to firebase.

```
 exports.sendSignUpNotification =functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
const user_id = context.params.userId;
//const notifID = context.params.notification_id;
console.log("User id at signup:\t", user_id);
//console.log("Notification id at signup:\t", notifID);

let token = admin.database().ref(`/users/{userId}/id_token`).once('value');
console.log("User id token:\t", token);

 return new Promise().then(data => {
    const payLoad = {
    notification: {
       title: "Thank You For Signing Up",
       body: "Enjoy the best features by becoming a premium user"
     }
   };
   return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payLoad);
 }).catch(errs => {
  console.error("Error Sending Payload", errs);
});

});
```

This is the edited code for the full function but somehow I know that I'm doing sth wrong while sending the payload. This is the error I am getting below:

```
TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function
at exports.sendSignUpNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:15:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:716:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

and to get the token on client side, I have called this method on signup:

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "idToken:\t" + idToken);

                                    HashMap<String, String> usersMap = new HashMap<>();
                                    usersMap.put("name", name);
                                    usersMap.put("userId", userId);
                                    usersMap.put("email", email);
                                    usersMap.put("id_token", idToken);
          }
```

I have saved this token and referenced it in my script for cloud function. Is this the right token or should I use the one from `FirebaseInstanceIdService` like below:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();

    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed Token:\t" + refreshedToken);

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the old beta API with the new 1.x version of the SDK.  The way that database events work has changed.  The changes for the entire SDK are summarized [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff).  onWrite events now take two parameters, a change and a context.  The change contains the before and after snapshots, and the context contains the wildcard values.

To get the userId wildcard, you would now say:

```
exports.sendSignUpNotification = functions.database.ref(`/users/{userId}`).onWrite((change, context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId
```

Please see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) for more current examples.

Also in your code this line has a bug:

```
let token = admin.database().ref(`/users/{userId}/notificationTokens`).once('value');
```

The JavaScript syntax for variable interpolation in a backtick delimited string requires a dollar sign:

```
`/users/${userId}/notificationTokens`
```

That line has yet another bug.  You're not making use of the promise returned by once() to actually get a hold of the value in the database.  `token` is going to contain that promise, not the contents of the database.

And you're also going to have to return a promise that resolves when all the async work is done in the function, which you're currently not doing.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. The log is showing now, however there's a little problem, it also shows this: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value, how do I resolve this?

Comment: My answer goes over all the problems in your code, including the one you just mentioned.

Comment: Okay, I have just read it now. One more doubt I am having is, to send notification to device using functions, do I get the token from firebase messaging service on the client side and give the path to the token, like I did above or mint a new token server side and push the notification. Please which is a better approach?

Comment: You can't create your own messaging tokens.  They must come from the client device.

Comment: I have edited the question to help you address my confusion on the token. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a follow-up question that's different than the first, you should ask it separately rather than dragging out the first one.

Comment: Thanks Doug, but how do I solve the expected Promise warning? THanks again