# Firebase Cloud Functions Error with CanonicalRegistrationTokenCount

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a signup notification to my app after registration and user has been saved in db. I am using firebase cloud functions for this purpose.

I have gotten the device token from firebaseinstanceidservice and saved that in the user's db with the path `users/userid/deviceToken` and referenced this path in the function like below code:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("users/{userId}/{instanceId_token}")
```

I have tried logging the devicetoken just to be sure but in cloud console, I keep getting other attributes for that log like : `sendNotification
deviceToken name`, `sendNotification
deviceToken userId` instead of the alphanumeric value saved in db. Is this path wrong?

Here's my full code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database.ref("users/{userId}/{instanceId_token}")
    .onWrite((changes, context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    console.log("user-id", userId);
    const notificationToken = context.params.instanceId_token;
    console.log("deviceToken", notificationToken);

    var payload = {
      data: {
          title: "Welcome to My Group",
          message: "You may have new messages"
      }
    };
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(notificationToken, payload)
      .then(function (response) {
          return console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
         return console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
      })
  });
```

Also, the function shows this mildly positive message, after the `admin.messaging` callback:

```
Successfully sent message:  { results: [ { error: [Object] } ],
   canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
   failureCount: 1,
   successCount: 0,
   multicastId: 8880906162831350000 }
```

How do I resolve this, I am using an android client?

Here's my db structure:
[image]

Comment: Could you add an export of your database in your question?

Comment: I have edited the question. Have a look now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trigger you function on the upper node, as follows. And access the `instanceId_token` through `changes.after.val()`.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database.ref("users/{userId}")
    .onWrite((changes, context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    console.log("user-id", userId);
    const notificationToken = changes.after.val().instanceId_token;
    console.log("deviceToken", notificationToken);



    var payload = {
      data: {
          title: "Welcome to My Group",
          message: "You may have new messages"
      }
    };

  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(notificationToken, payload)
      .catch(function (error) {
         console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
      })
  });
```

---

In case you add the `instanceId_token` ONLY AFTER having created the user, then you should trigger with `onUpdate()` (which "triggers when data is updated", while `onWrite()` "triggers when data is created, updated, or deleted").

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database.ref("users/{userId}")
    .onUpdate((changes, context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    console.log("user-id", userId);
    const notificationToken = changes.after.val().instanceId_token;
    console.log("deviceToken", notificationToken);

    if (notificationToken === undefined) {
        console.log("notificationToken === undefined");
      return false;
    } else {

       var payload = {
          data: {
             title: "Welcome to My Group",
             message: "You may have new messages"
         }
       };
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(notificationToken, payload)
         .catch(function (error) {
             console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
         })    
       }
  });
```

---

Also note that you should not do

```
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(notificationToken, payload)
      .then(function (response) {
          return console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
         return console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
      });
```

because in this case you are not returning a promise "that resolves when all the async work is done in the function". (see the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651565/firebase-cloud-function-finished-with-status-error))

So just return the promise returned by sendToDevice (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendToDevice)), as follows:

```
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(notificationToken, payload)
      .catch(function (error) {
         console.log("Error sending message: ", error);  // here no return
      });
```

Comment: It's not working bro, the first one throws error and the second one doesn't show notification. The device id is not logged in both cases.

Comment: Mmhhhh... I can confirm that the two following `console.log` works correctly (`console.log("user-id", userId);`
    and 
    `console.log("deviceToken", notificationToken);`) print the correct values for the onWrite, I've tested it. If you get an error it is probably with the sendToDevice(). Your code looks ok for this part, so maybe it is due to a wrong token? For the second case, actually I was in a hurry when I included it in my answer and I copied/pasted your own code (hence the error)! I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Andromeda can you give another try, I've 'fine tuned' my answer.

Comment: @Andromeda I see you have accepted the answer, thanks. If you think my answer is appropriate would you mind also upvoting it, by clicking the large up arrow to the left of a post? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up. Thanks