# Firebase Functions Finished with status: error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing my first Firebase Function that is supposed to make a collection with a document inside (in Firestore) when a new user registers. The only logs I am getting are the following:

> Function execution started

and

> Function execution took 194 ms. Finished with status: error.

The versions of the dependencies:

```
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
"firebase-functions": "^3.20.0"
```

This is my code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    return db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .create(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)));
});
```

When I tried outputting the user.uid in the logs with

```
return functions.logger.log(user.uid);
```

I got the expected results as it output the uid as requested, meaning that the problem isn't with getting the user.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651565/firebase-cloud-function-finished-with-status-error), but it didn't solve my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: That's all you see in the log, those two lines?  Are you sure that this is doing exactly what you expect?  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)))`?

Comment: What happens when you replace `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)))` with a hard-coded test/dummy argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this for anyone that comes across the same problem in the future! I wrote an email to the firebase support, they gave me the following answer:

> Regarding this same error, we have received a couple of similar reports these past few days.

and

> There is already an escalation placed for this.

Update: They have already fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error because I was using the command : "firebase deploy " to deploy the function but when I used the command : "firebase deploy --only functions " the function gets deployed successfully.